# Why ZDesigner GX420d printer show 1 inc Top margin?

Tags: c#, .net, printing, zebra-printers, zpl

I am very new in ZPL and try to learn it. I am wright some code for label to print but i get unexpected result. ZDesigner GX420d printer is always show 1 inc Top margin.

Here is my ZPL Code :

```
CT~~CD,~CC^~CT~
^XA~TA000~JSN^LT0^MNW^MTD^PON^PMN^LH0,0^JMA^PR3,3~SD8^JUS^LRN^CI0^XZ
^XA
^MMT
^PW812
^LL0609
^LS0
^FT13,41^A0N,28,28^FH\^FDShip From :^FS
^FT13,75^A0N,28,28^FH\^FDAG Hair CosmZticsfwZfZwfwZfwZfwZ^FS
^FT13,109^A0N,28,28^FH\^FD8021 EntZrprisZ StrZZt^FS
^FT13,142^A0N,28,28^FH\^FDBurnaby, BC Canada V5A 1V5^FS
^FT12,216^A0N,28,28^FH\^FDINV#B32184^FS
^FT566,218^A0N,28,28^FH\^FDDZlivZry 11/8/2013^FS
^FT11,274^A0N,28,28^FH\^FDATTN : (ATTN)^FS
^FT590,273^A0N,28,28^FH\^FDCUST #(TYHA01)^FS
^FT10,348^A0N,28,28^FH\^FDShip To :^FS
^FT10,382^A0N,28,28^FH\^FDTY HAIR DESIGN^FS
^FT10,416^A0N,28,28^FH\^FD113-7320 KING GEORGE HWY^FS
^FT10,450^A0N,28,28^FH\^FDSURREY^FS
^FT738,530^A0N,28,28^FH\^FDCOD^FS
^FT11,528^A0N,28,28^FH\^FD( 1 OF 1) PiZcZs^FS
^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ
```

My output is :

[image]

In ZebraDesigner Pro 2 : 
[image]

I do not understand what is happening.

I defiantly do something wrong but do not know there.

**Update :**

I install `ZDesigner GX420d driver`

And Use Below code For Printing :

```
 RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter("ZDesigner GX420d", command);

 public static bool SendStringToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szString)
    {
        IntPtr pBytes;
        Int32 dwCount;
        // How many characters are in the string?
        dwCount = szString.Length;
        // Assume that the printer is expecting ANSI text, and then convert
        // the string to ANSI text.
        pBytes = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(szString);
        // Send the converted ANSI string to the printer.
        SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pBytes, dwCount);
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pBytes);
        return true;
    }
```

I use [RawPrinterHelper](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091) for send ZPL to Printer.

Comment: Are you sending the ZPL using the ZDesigner driver?  I tried printing it and it looks ok with no margin, perhaps there is some other driver setting adding that margin?  Try changing the ^MNW to ^MNN as a test, that will put it in continuous mode and the label should be exactly 609 high (your ^LL length)

Comment: @OviTisler I Update my question description. Please take a look if i do something wrong. Thank you.

Comment: if you are using the driver there's probably some setting that is adding some margin, i would check that first

Comment: My ZPL is rusty so I'm not sure if you're expressly setting a label size... the last time I saw something like this, the printer was configured with an incorrect label size.